# Building a Grdivew with Web Service Data

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

Hi i am trying to build a Gridview Based on my Web Service Data.

I am not not getting any errors when I compile the code, however the gridview does not display.  Not sure if this is because I am building the gridview wrong or the data is not being pulled correctly.  The web service does work because I have tested it.

Here is the code i am using to bind the gridview:

```
Private Sub BindGrid()
    Dim objVen As New ISISVendor.VendorInterfaceClient
    Dim LoginResp As New ISISVendor.LoginResponse
    Dim POResp As New ISISVendor.PoSummaryResponse
    Dim pod As New ISISVendor.PoDetailResponse

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("Status")
    dt.Columns.Add("Sender")
    dt.Columns.Add("PO Number")
    dt.Columns.Add("Date")
    dt.Columns.Add("Action")
    gvv.DataSource = dt

    POResp = objVen.GetOpenPos("3274")
    Dim dr As DataRow

    If POResp.Pos.Count > 0 Then


        For j As Integer = 0 To POResp.Pos.Count - 1
            dr = dt.NewRow
            dr.Item("Status") = POResp.Pos(j).Status
            dr.Item("Sender") = "COMPANY TEST"
            dr.Item("PO Number") = POResp.Pos(j).PoNumber
            dr.Item("Date") = POResp.Pos(j).PoDate
            dr.Item("Action") = ""


        Next
    End If
    gvv.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: `dr = dt.NewRow` needs to be in the loop

Comment: Tried adding that.  Still not displaying anything

Comment: Did you check the `POResp.Pos` object to see if it is populated?

Comment: Yes it populates 45 items

Comment: Did you try `gvv.DataSource = POResp.Pos` instead of the DataTable?

Comment: Just tried that.  Changed gvv.DataSource = dt to gvv.DataSource = POResp.Pos still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem you are not adding the datarow to the data table
Please try as below

```
POResp = objVen.GetOpenPos("3274")
Dim dr As DataRow

If POResp.Pos.Count > 0 Then


    For j As Integer = 0 To POResp.Pos.Count - 1
        dr = dt.NewRow
        dr.Item("Status") = POResp.Pos(j).Status
        dr.Item("Sender") = "COMPANY TEST"
        dr.Item("PO Number") = POResp.Pos(j).PoNumber
        dr.Item("Date") = POResp.Pos(j).PoDate
        dr.Item("Action") = ""

        dt.Rows.Add(dr)


    Next
End If
gvv.DataSource = dt
gvv.DataBind()
```